# How to get auto-suggestion when we style a components inside react.js file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

When we style elements using the app.css or styles.css, vs code simply auto suggest us. example if we type just "back" for background colour, it auto suggest us to complete. but in react.js or index.js it won't work.  Why? is there any idea or solution for this? An extension or something. Please excuse my poor english.

solution for this auto-suggestion/auto-complete of this.

Answer (score 0):

In vs code the suggestions are based on the file extension. Therefore, in a js file the vs code only expect JavaScript and it gives suggestions on that. You can use commonly available react extension like [ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets)
 for getting react snippets, component name autocomplete.

Comment: i've already installed it. but no use. Iam working on with react jsx files.